# Updated WordPress, "Cannot redeclare has_shortcode" error is thrown

Tags: php, wordpress

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare has_shortcode() (previously declared in /home/content/86/9216686/html/wordpress/wp-includes/shortcodes.php:153) in /home/content/86/9216686/html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/options/framework/functions/common.php on line 23

Comment: Can you post some code?? Because without code we can say: "hmmm, nice fatal error" only

Comment: What would I need to post? I just updated wordpress and I have a feeling the theme is incompatible

Comment: `has_shortcode()` has been already declared in Wordpress core file. Your theme framework also contain the same function.

Comment: At the very least the theme should be using function_exists to prevent these errors! Looks like you'll have to update it.

Answer (score 1):

The function `has_shortcode` was introduced in WordPress 3.6, you probably updated from an earlier version.

[image]

Now the theme is trying to use a reserved function. Meaning: the theme is outdated, solutions:

- update to a newer version of the theme.
- contact the author and report.
- encapsulate the theme function <sup>(wp-content/themes/options/framework/functions/common.php)</sup> with

  ```
  if( !function_exists( 'has_shortcode' ) )
  {
      function has_shortcode() 
      {
          // THE THEME CODE
      }
  }
  ```